# Can I uncommented a line of commented code in a javascript function after it is loaded in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, testing, dom, comments

I'm testing a webpage with javascript commented out - I'd like to test the commented functionality and do not have the option to push a new version of the page with the comment notation removed.

Is there a way (using firefox console perhaps?) to remove the comment notation and re-enable a portion of a script already loaded on a page?

---

EDIT: The code I'm trying to access is loaded via a file `file.js` and the section I wish to run looks like this - located entirely between comment delimiters:

```
/*$(document).CommentedFunction(function(event) {
    if ...<snip>... {
    }

});*/
```

Comment: maybe the following can help: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools#overrides but you need to reload the page.

Comment: If your script works in the global scope, copy/paste it in the js console. For more complex scripts try TamperMonkey

Comment: I looked quickly at TamperMonkey - it looks like a source for userscripts. Are you suggesting I copy/paste the script into TamperMonkey?